# Is my logic for a .tell ( notification ) function on my IRC bot sound?

Tags: language-agnostic, irc

I have a bot in node.js and I'm wondering what logic I should use for a `.tell` function. The purpose of the function will be to give a message to users who are offline. So, if `john` was offline on freenode.net/#foo and I typed `.tell john your mother was great last night`, I want the bot to store this message and display it whenever `john` joins the channel.

If `john` is already in the channel, I want the bot to immediately just display the message.

I am already using `mongodb` as a database to store information, so I can probably store all my messages in there. Here's the logic I had in mind so far:

**1.** After user A types `.tell john your mother was great`, a listener will pickup the pattern `/\.tell ([\w-]+) (.*)/` and store a variable for the message ( `var msg`, the user who posted the message ( `var from` ), and the name of the user to be messaged ( `var to` ). I will also have a global variable signifying the channel name and network of the server.

**2.** I'll store a row in mongodb such as:

```
to   from   message                 network       channel        delivered   time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
john meder  your mother was great   freenode.net  #foobar        0           (TS)
            last night
```

**3.** Setup a listener for *anyone* joining a channel since the bot can live in multiple channels under *one* network, and detect if there any messages that are not delivered and if there are, attempt to match the `to` and `network` and `channel` to the stored messages, and if row(s) are found, display them.

This sounds ok, but can anyone review it and maybe offer advice? I'll be forced to have a listener listen for anyone entering any channel, right? There's no alternative to that?

Comment: Actually, instead of `offline` I mean in the channel. They have to be in the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems all fine. I don't see how you could not have a listener.

One thing I'd add is maybe a hash in the bot to keep track of who has pending messages. This way you won't be querying MongoDB every time someone joins a channel.

I.e.

```
messages = {};
messages['freenode.net'] = {};
messages['freenode.net']['john'] = 1;
```

Might be overkill, but if your monitoring a channel that has many JOINs, you might find yourself querying MongoDB a lot.

My two cents.

- Christian